# ruby - using include method in a case statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, switch-statement, case

I'm using something like this:

```
case referer
      when (referer.include? "some_string")
        redirect_link = edit_product_path
      when (referer.include? "some_other_string")
        redirect_link = other_product_path
end
```

Unfortunately, this returns nil even if the string `some_string` is present in the variable `referer`.

Here's what i tried in Ruby Console:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :006 > jasdeep = "RAILS"
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :026 > case jasdeep
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :027?>   when (jasdeep.include? "AI")
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :028?>   puts "Hello"
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :029?> end
=> nil
```

Any inputs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this

```
jasdeep = "RAILS"
case jasdeep
when /IL/
  puts "Hello"
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with variables in the `when` boolean?

Comment: @Nick it's possible:
```when /#{some_var}/
  puts "variable"
end```

Comment: what the hell IL is?

Comment: @Unkas it's part of the tested string as RegEx (`/IL/` in `jasdeep = "RAILS"`)

Answer (score 3):

```
jasdeep = "RAILS"

case
  when jasdeep.include?("AI")
    puts "Hello"
end
```

Comment: Thanks Nash, but that did'nt helped.

Answer (score 0):

That nil is the returned value from the puts statement, not from .include?. Try to run the following two statements separately from the console and observe the returned value:

```
jasdeep.include? "AI"

puts "hello"
```

Comment: `ruby-1.8.7-p334 :040 > puts "hello"
hello
 => nil `

Answer (score 0):

```
case true
when referer.include? "some_string"
  redirect_link = edit_product_path
when referer.include? "some_other_string"
  redirect_link = other_product_path
end
```

Comment: This results in a `syntax error` with Ruby 1.9.3 (as well as later versions I'd imagine).